# How to implement Dojo autocomplete similar to jQuery UI autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, dojo

Good day, using JSP and jQuery UI I have successfuly implemented autocompletion for a text input. Autocomplete data  are retrieved from a database and filtered by 'q' parameter on the server side. It returns all items containing queried string:

```
SELECT name FROM organization WHERE name LIKE '%q%';
```

Is there a way how to do the same with Dojo? I followed this [Dojo tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/data/QueryReadStore/example.html) , but when I type for example letter `a` into the text input the text in the text input get's replaced by first suggestion `Ibam` and my first letter `a` is replaced with `I` from word `Ibam`. It works strange. Please advise.

Vojtech

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend [`dijit/form/ComboBox`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/ComboBox) with [`dojo/store/JsonRest`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/store/JsonRest).

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/N8DqG/

Comment: Many thanks, this helped me. Suggestions based on query 'like "%q%"' don't work anyway but the example on jsfiddle was helpful to me.